# Why does my code only store the last word from a file using fscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

the printf statement here only prints out the last word inside of the file. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    char string[100];
    fp = fopen("exam.txt", "r");
    c = getc(fp);
    while(c!=EOF)
    { 
        fscanf(fp, "%s", string);
        c = getc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s", string);
    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: Specify a width when you read a string with `*scanf` to avoid overflows (and don't remove indentation added by other people).

Comment: Sorry effeffe. I realized the code I inserted was wrong so needed to change it. What was wrong with my indentation?

Comment: Yes I saw your change. Well, there was no indentation. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you only print once at the end...

```
printf("%s", string);
```

You need to print inside this loop:

```
while(c!=EOF)
{ 
    fscanf(fp, "%99s", string);
    printf("%s\n", string);  // now you can see the files as you read it.
     c = getc(fp);
}
```

if you want to see each line. You're just overwriting `string` each time.

Also, you don't initialize `int c` before using it.

Break down of `fscanf()`:

```
 fscanf(fp,       // read from here   (file pointer to your file)
        "%99s",   // read this format (string up to 99 characters)
         string); // store the data here (your char array)
```

Your loop condition is while the next character isn't EOF meaning End Of File (a condition that happens after all the data has been read out of the file)

So:

```
while (we're not at the end of the file)
     read up a line and store it in string
     get the next character
```

You'll note your algorithm doesn't check for anything in that string, it just writes to it. This will overwrite the data in there each time. That's why you only see the last line from your file, because you keep over writing `string` and the last thing in there happens to be the last line you read before seeing the EOF character and breaking out of the while loop.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the EOF after the end of each \n in the file in order to be able to keep all words in the variable?

Comment: @the5thace - `EOF after the end of each \n in the file ` - I'm not quite sure what you're saying here... There's only 1 EOF and that's at the very end of the file. If you want to concatenate all the strings in the file, you can do that but you'll need another variable big enought for the whole file. I would recomend getting the size of the file then `malloc` a `char *` big enought for that task

Comment: From your explanation I assumed there is EOF after each line. Why does it overwrite the string if EOF only occurs once?

Comment: @the5thace - OK, I reedited the answer to try and spell it out. Did that help?

Comment: EOF is actualy not a character in your file, it is a convenience value returned by functions reading files to indicates they reach End Of File. Given that definition... your while { } exits only when it reach end of file.  BUT fscanf reads one line after the other due to %s which means to read any not white space character where white space character is ( see isspace ). Globally : see man fscanf.

Comment: I understand just as much as before to be honest. If it loops through each character until EOF then that means it loops through only once. Then how does it overwrite it? Is it because of the memory?

Comment: @the5thace - Ignore the `EOF` for a second. `fscanf(fp, "%s", string)` is reading a string from file pointer and storing it to the variable "string". That's like if I did: `int x = 1;` and then `x = 2;`. You wouldn't expect `x` to have `1` stored in it right? Same thing is happening here. You're reading the file, line by line and at each line end (ended by white space, tab, or newline) you're storing the result into `string`. Again and again different content is being stored into the same `string` variable. Once you hit the end of the file, only the last thing you read is left in the string.

Comment: Think I get. So the fgets asks string to only store one string in to it. And each string is only as long as the number of characters inside of it. So when it reaches a non character it overwrites it?

Comment: @the5thace - Yeah, that's pretty much it. I'd replace `when it reaches a non character` with `when it's done reading`. `fscanf("%s")` takes a string, and stops at "white space" (spaces, newlines, etc).  `fscanf("%[^\n]")` however will read until it hits a newline (or EOF). How long, and what, fscanf reads is totally determined by what you type in that format string. That's why something like `getline` is easier to use.